# A:link supersedes .class A:link?

Tags: html, css

I got a css that looks like this:

```
.browse-link A:link { 
    color: #F6CA4C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.browse-link A:hover {
    color: #F6CA4C;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.browse-link A:visited {
    color: #F6CA4C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.browse-link A:active {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: none;
}

A:link {
    COLOR: #0000FF; text-decoration: none;
}
A:visited {
    COLOR: #0000FF; text-decoration: none;
}
A:active {
    COLOR: #0000FF; text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover {
    COLOR: #FF0000; text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is how the html looks like:

```
<table style="border:0; margin:0; padding:0;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a class="browse-link" href="http://www.revheal.com/en/users/login/http://www.revheal.com/">Login</a>
         </td>
         <td>
            <a class="browse-link" href="http://www.revheal.com/en/users/register/">Register</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to have only the "login" "register" and "Browse all" links located in the header part of the website (blue background) to be yellowish.

Looking in the firebug, it's A:link which is applied.

So far I've been rather unsuccessful. What should I do to make them look yellow?

Comment: The background is blue so I want the text yellow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your markup is

```
<a class="browse-link">Browse all</a>
```

your CSS would have to be

```
a.browse-link:link /* NOT .browse-link a:link */
```

Comment: Sweet it works! But I can't accept an answer yet :( I'm so bad at css. Keep learning!